# How to avoid angular markup to show up when JavaScript code breaks and throws an exception?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

AngularJS markup shows all the hidden error messages, images, data in the markup if JavaScript breaks somewhere.

I saw ng-cloak but it only works to keep markup hidden till angular loads up.

Is there a way to avoid the UI getting disrupted when JS breaks ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes : don't let JavaScript throw an uncatched exception in a production environment. That the purpose of **unit testing**, and [one of the (numerous) advantages of AngularJS](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/unit-testing).